# ProgressBar 2 colors

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I have a question about `ProgressBar` in WPF in C#. I want that my `progressBar` will have 2 colors. For example I set his max value to 25 and in seventh and fifth iteration something goes wrong and I want it in red color in my `progressbar`. 
I added example picture what I want gain to.

[image]

Comment: The answer mentioned in the previous comment is for Windows.Forms, while the OP's question is about WPF. While it still holds that he'll need to "superclass" his control (with custom style template?), the method would be completely different.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `GradiantBrush` and set the `GradientStops` based on your logic, the only downside to this solution is that `GradientStops` aren't bindable so you have to set them from code. Here is a simple taste:

```
 <ProgressBar Width="500" Value="70" Height="30">
        <ProgressBar.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0" >

                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.3" />
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.3" />
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1" />

            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ProgressBar.Foreground>
    </ProgressBar>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: But how can I solve problem:
My progressbar maximum value depends of count of lines in text file (it can be different, one time 3 lines, one time 1238) and for instance this 1238 lines then 5 random operations will be failed which every operation is point in my progressbar. How can I bind maximum value from program to xaml and how can i use it at all? What I see is percentage fill of color of progressbar and I do not really know how can i do that?

Comment: The offset in the LinearGradientBrush Goes from 0 to 1, you could simply map that to your lines count (by changing the scale), each time something goes wrong in your progress just add two GradientStop (a green one to end the previous progress, and a red one to start presenting the fail) etc...

Comment: Ok, thanks i got that. But how can I set a variable into xaml file?

Comment: Give the above LinearGradientBrush a name, lets say: `Name="MyLinearGradiantBrush"`, now GradientStop can't be added from xaml (they arn't FrameworkElements so they can't be bound), add them from code behind when needed :`MyLinearGradiantBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Red, _yourCalculatedOffset));`

Comment: I counting my offset in DivideImage.cs (class) not MainWindows.xaml.cs so what should i do to get access to them? Sorry but I am freshly with WPF.

Comment: If you have a Collection of offsets defined in another class, at some point you need to instanciate that class in your main viewModel (or in MainWindows.xaml.cs), define that collection as a property and use it in the MainWindows.xaml.cs.
I am sorry, but this is the best i can do with out seeing your code ;), pls add more description/code to your question if you want more precise help :))